# How to handle changing a function used in multiple places?

Tags: python

I'm using python.

I have a function that is being used in multiple places across my code. The function returns a tuple with 4 values.

Say I now change the function to return an additional value (for a total of 5).

Now I am in the hassle to change the amount of returned variables in every place I used that function.

What programming practice do you guys recommend I could implement as not to fall into this issue of having to change every instance of where the functioned was used?

Thank you.

I want to be able to change the function and do minimal work to update the rest of my code. Not sure if using a python class, decorator, closure, or any other method would be best.

Comment: If you return an object, you can have named fields on the object which contain the values you want; if you want to add a 5th value, for example, you can just start referring to the 5th field where you need it, but there's no need to retroactively change anything.

Comment: I'm guessing your code looked like `a, b, c, d = func(args)`, and you now would have to change everything to `a, b, c, d, e = func(args)` but I'm proposing it works like `custom_object = func(args)`, and then you can do something like `custom_object.a` to get the `a` value.

Comment: @RandomDavis That makes sense. Instead of limiting my code by returning "a, b, c, d", I just return an object, say Dog, and access its members as I need them. I also only need to change the Dog definition in one place, not in every instance of the function.

Comment: yes, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 0):

Not great practice, but a minimal way to do this is to add an optional parameter that changes whether the output is four or five outputs. This allows your old code to function as before, while new code that requires the fifth output just needs to add in the parameter.

```
def fourorfive(five = False):
    if five:
        return 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    else:
        return 1, 2, 3, 4

a, b, c, d = fourorfive()

a2, b2, c2, d2, e2 = fourorfive(five = True)
```